# When is it beneficial to add -u to tr?

Tags: performance, stdout, tr, buffer

One of the arguments to the `tr` command is:

> `-u`      Guarantee that any output is unbuffered.

Under what circumstances is it a good idea to not buffer the output?

e.g. should I use `-u` if I expect each line to be super long?

e.g. should I use `-u` if I'm memory constrained?

e.g. if I pipe this into `awk` (which processes files line by line), then does that mean it's better to use buffered output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unbuffered output is less efficient so if there is a lot of it, it will be slower.  Unbuffered output could potentially do a system call for every character (although usually not).

The advantage is that you get the output immediately, rather than when the buffer fills up and is flushed.  For output that is slow (like one line or less at a time), and being interactively viewed, this would be better.

In Unix, output is typically either block buffered or line buffered, and rarely, unbuffered.

You can change the default for a command with the `stdbuf` command, which is part of GNU coreutils.